# JavaScript Assignment Operator in 'while' loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, assignment-operator

I have a script:

```
<script>  
var text = "";  
var i = 0;  
while (i < 10) {  
text += i;  
i++;   
} 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;  
</script>
```

This script will write the numbers 0 ....9
**Why I have to use the "text += i" assignment?**
**why can't I code "text = i" instead?**
How would you explain this code line?
Thanks for your time!

ps. I know `text += i` is equivalent to

```
text = text + i
```

this is not a question here. ;)
and I also know if I type "text = i" I will get just the last number: 9.

Comment: What? You answer your own question in your (ps), no?

Comment: I don't understand why I have to declare that text is equal with "text" + "i", instead of "text" is equal "i"

Comment: "declare" what? You're not "declaring" anything by using `+=`. It means, "add the value on the right to the value on the left, and save the result to the variable on the left."

Comment: Have you compared the output of using `+=` vs. `=`? They're very different. So you use `+=` for one and `=` for another. You already understand what each operator does and what happens if you just assign directly. What aren't you understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The plain assignment operator `=` sets the variable (or object property) on the left side to the value on the right. The former value of the left side variable is lost.

The `+=` operator performs an addition between the current left side value and the right side value, and then assigns that result to the left side. If you want to *accumulate* a series of addition operations into a variable, then, you would use `+=`.

If you just use `=`, then, the variable `text` will retain only the last value assigned.

That's the way the assignment operator works in a vast number of languages like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its good that you know how operators works ...so let me clarify why the script is using 
text+=i

Lets walk through the loop
Initially text=''
For first time it comes in 
Text='0'
So now if you were appending the text to div, then you could have set it to blank string again or used text=i

But you are not adding the text to div.
So if we use text =i  the text becomes 0
And in next becomes 1 and so on at the end its value will be 9
But we wanted 0...9 so we have to keep appending the string value of numbers
To get 0...9